# Can't change the border form of images on a Map to circles in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I am currently developing a web application using AngularJS, in which i have included a Google Map API, the problem here is I cannot change the image form on the MAP API from squares to circles, here is how they look like :[image: Map screenshot]

here is the `html` part of it :

```
<!-- Maps View -->
    <ui-gmap-google-map 
            center="map.center"  
            zoom="map.zoom" 
            draggable="true"
            options="options"
            dragging="map.dragging" 
            bounds="map.bounds">
            <ui-gmap-markers  
                  models="agentsMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" fit='true' 
                  doCluster="true" clusterEvents="clusterEvents"
                  click="onMarkerClicked">
            </ui-gmap-markers>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Here is the `Controller` of the `map config` :

```
//maps config
      $scope.map = {
        center:{ latitude: 54.218417,longitude: 10.031353},
        zoom: 15,
        bounds: {}
      };
      $scope.options = { scrollwheel: false, icon:'url/icon.png'};
```

And here is how the bounds and markers are set:

```
 // Get the bounds from the map once it's loaded
      $scope.$watch(function() {
        return $scope.map.bounds;}, function(nv, ov) {
        // Only need to regenerate once
        if (!ov.southwest && nv.southwest) {
          var markers = [];
          for (var i=0; i<$scope.List.length; i++) {

            markers.push(createAgentMarker(i, $scope.map.bounds,$scope.agentList[i]));
          }

          _.each(markers, function (marker) {
            marker.onMarkerClicked = function () {
              onMarkerClicked(marker);
            };

          });

          $scope.agentMarkers = markers;
        }
      }, true);
```